# Getting "vote is not defined" javascript error

Tags: support, javascript

I'm getting this error when viewing questions. It's preventing voting from working for me.

Happening on SO, SF and SU with Firefox 3.5.13

Comment: Working fine with latest version of Chrome

Comment: Saw this again today, clearing cache fixed it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your cache is out of date for some reason.

(some corporate proxies are known to inappropriately serve cached versions of old files even though every one we serve has a version # string in the URL)

Clear your cache and try again.

Comment: Guess it was my browser cache.  Oddly I was able to upvote your answer here before clearing it.  Do the other sites share their js files?